# how to replace legend 'bullet' of geom_text guide (legend)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to replace the 'bullets' in legend (guide) of `geom_text`. Now it's a tilted `a`, but I would like a big fat circle or a square or any other shape that will emphasize the color (more).

```
library(ggplot2)

majdf <- data.frame(lvl = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 50), val = c(rnorm(50, 1), rnorm(50, 3)))
majtxt <- data.frame(species = c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3"), geq = c(0.01, 2, 2.2))

ggplot(majdf, aes(x = val)) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(data = majtxt, aes(xintercept = geq)) +
  geom_text(data = majtxt, aes(x = geq, y = 0.2, label = geq, color = species), angle = 90) +
  facet_wrap(~ lvl)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ggplot(majdf, aes(x = val)) +
  geom_point(data = majtxt, aes(x = geq, colour = species), 
             y = 0.2, size = 0) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(data = majtxt, aes(xintercept = geq)) +
  geom_text(data = majtxt, aes(x = geq, y = 0.2, label = geq, color = species), 
            angle = 90, show_guide = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ lvl) +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=4)))
```

[image]

How this works: Add a point geom with the appropriate colour mapping. This will add a point into the legend. But, to keep it from showing up on the the plot, set the size of the point to 0. In the text geom, tell it not to add that part (the rotated a) to the legend (`show_guide = FALSE`). Finally, the legend will have just the point that you want and not the sideways a; unfortunately, it is drawn at the same size as in the plot, namely 0. So using the `override.aes` argument to `guide_legend` (which is passed to `guide` in `scale_colour_discrete`), set the size of the point to something "big".

This approach does not require pulling apart pieces to two different plots and stitching them back together.

An alternative way of specifying the guide parameters is using the `guides` function instead of passing it as an argument to `scale_colour_manual`:

```
ggplot(majdf, aes(x = val)) +
  geom_point(data = majtxt, aes(x = geq, colour = species), 
             y = 0.2, size = 0) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(data = majtxt, aes(xintercept = geq)) +
  geom_text(data = majtxt, aes(x = geq, y = 0.2, label = geq, color = species), 
            angle = 90, show_guide = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ lvl) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=4)))
```

The resulting graphic is the same.

Comment: If you are breaking your legend into more than 1 column, make sure to pass the number of columns through the scale, like this `scale_colour_discrete(guide = guide_legend(nrow = 2, override.aes = list(size = 4)))` otherwise hell breaks loose. Kudos to Didzis in the R chatroom: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14908487#14908487

Comment: did anyone figure out why override.aes doesn't play well with geom_text?

Answer (score 6):

This is just a hack.

Create the plot with `geom_point`:

```
p1 <- ggplot(majdf, aes(x = val)) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(data = majtxt, aes(xintercept = geq)) +
  geom_point(data = majtxt, aes(x = geq, y = 0.2, label = geq, color = species), angle = 90) +
  facet_wrap(~ lvl)
```

The same with `geom_text`:

```
p2 <- ggplot(majdf, aes(x = val)) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(data = majtxt, aes(xintercept = geq)) +
  geom_text(data = majtxt, aes(x = geq, y = 0.2, label = geq, color = species), angle = 90) +
  facet_wrap(~ lvl)
```

Turn into a grob and find which element is the guide:

```
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g1

TableGrob (8 x 10) "layout": 13 grobs
    z         cells       name                                     grob
1   0 ( 1- 8, 1-10) background          rect[plot.background.rect.2339]
2   1 ( 4- 4, 4- 4)    panel-1                gTree[panel-1.gTree.2263]
3   2 ( 4- 4, 7- 7)    panel-2                gTree[panel-2.gTree.2278]
4   3 ( 3- 3, 4- 4)  strip_t-1    absoluteGrob[strip.absoluteGrob.2306]
5   4 ( 3- 3, 7- 7)  strip_t-2    absoluteGrob[strip.absoluteGrob.2312]
6   5 ( 4- 4, 3- 3)   axis_l-1 absoluteGrob[axis-l-1.absoluteGrob.2299]
7   6 ( 4- 4, 6- 6)   axis_l-2         zeroGrob[axis-l-2.zeroGrob.2300]
8   7 ( 5- 5, 4- 4)   axis_b-1 absoluteGrob[axis-b-1.absoluteGrob.2285]
9   8 ( 5- 5, 7- 7)   axis_b-2 absoluteGrob[axis-b-2.absoluteGrob.2292]
10  9 ( 7- 7, 4- 7)       xlab             text[axis.title.x.text.2314]
11 10 ( 4- 4, 2- 2)       ylab             text[axis.title.y.text.2316]
12 11 ( 4- 4, 9- 9)  guide-box                        gtable[guide-box]
13 12 ( 2- 2, 4- 7)      title               text[plot.title.text.2337]
```

Copy the guide:

```
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
g2[[1]][[12]] <- g1[[1]][[12]]
plot(g2)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this give the big fat circle/square requested?