# R - Changing shape only in legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My plot currently looks like this:

[image: Plot]

I want to change the shape in the legend (which is currently "a") for only points that indicate the respective colours. This is my code so far:

```
ggplot(data=pca2.data, aes(x=X, y=Y, label=Sample, colour = col)) +
geom_text() +
xlab(paste("PC1 - ", pca2.var.per[1], "%", sep="")) +
ylab(paste("PC2 - ", pca2.var.per[2], "%", sep="")) +
theme_bw() +
ggtitle("My PCA Graph") +
geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "red", "green"), labels = c("No significant difference", "Sharpe Decrease", "Sharpe Increase")) +
theme(legend.position = 'bottom') + guides(color=guide_legend(""))
```

I already tried adding "shape = c(20, 20, 20)" inside of "guide_legend", but it changed nothing.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: Specifying `guide_legend(..., shape = ...)` is not going to do anything, you'd need the `guide_legend(..., override.aes = list(shape = ...))` to do that. More importantly, the "shape" aesthetic is not involved as no geom layer is generating a glyph with a shape parameter; you're seeing the legend for the `label` and `colour` aesthetics.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971963/how-to-replace-legend-bullet-of-geom-text-guide-legend

Answer (score 1):

Just put an empty point layer and don't plot legend for `geom_text`

As you didn't provide data, I've used `mtcars` dataset but it should translate to your problem

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl, label=rownames(mtcars), color=factor(carb))) +geom_point(shape=NA)+
  geom_text( show.legend = F ) + guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 16)))
```

Comment: This kinda works since it does indeed put the point shape in the legend. However it also plots points in each of the variables in the graph which in this case is not ideal...

Comment: Sorry the example I used I didn't notice the points. Set shape to NA in `geom_point()` and override the legend shape. I've updated the answer

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed. Thank you sir.